# Error on migration to non-deprecated ldap functions

Tags: c, openldap

I'm changing deprecated ldap functions to non-deprecated functions. But I am having problems with `ldap_sasl_bind_s. It returns error code 49`, which means invalid credentials. But I'm sure that the credentials are valid. Otherwise I added

```
TLS_REQCERT never

TLSVerifyClient never
```

to **/etc/openldap/ldap.conf**. Still I get the error.

```
ldap_simple_bind_s(q->ld, binddn, creds.bv_val);  //works well

ldap_sasl_bind_s(q->ld, binddn, LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE , &creds, NULL, NULL, NULL); //returns ldap error code 49 but continues working
```

The main problem is that : When i m using ldap_sasl_bind_s,  it doesnt bind all attrbiutes, that i got in my ldap architecture. Also when i m searching an existing attribute, it returns NOSUCH error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basic C programming covering the uber-basics, although something tells me you read this stuff already: (And I cannot tell from your question if your application is external or you are moving deprecated functions from the openldap? sources)

Have you read [this document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fldap_sasl_bind_s.htm) which indicates to me that `ldap_simple_bind` and `ldap_sasl_bind_s` will work the same if `char *LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE = 0;`